# Event based integration with versioned events

Tags: events, microservices, integration, event-based-programming

I want to communicate my services using events. I gonna publish (internally) all my domain events and allow any other service to subscribe to them. But such approach couples those services togheter. I am not longer allowed to change my events. This is even worse than local coupling because I dont event know my consumers any more. This limits the ability of developing/refactoring to unacceptable dedree. I am thinging about versioning my events which solves most of the issues. But how to subscribe to versioned events? Introducing common interface that groups all event`s versions and then downcast event within listener to accepted one does not sound like a vital solution. I also take into account publishing all supported versions of the event to the bus. By definition each subsriber will handle just one version. I dont want my domain to by involved in this matters so I need to build kind of infrastructure listener that will be translate catched events to other versions. I cant find anything about that topic in the Internet which automatically makes me think if I am not thoroughly wrong :)

UPDATE: After a lot of thought, I no longer want to publish my domain events. I think it is no desirable to expose internal service mechanics to the outer world. It also could violate some domain data access restriction. I think, the way to go is to map my domain events to some more corase integrational events. But I still need way to wersion them probably :)

UPDATE2: After some consultations an idea came up. Assuming we stick to the concept of integration events. Such events may be considered just as type and event id. So outer listener just focus on event type. If event occur then listener will be provided with event id. This enable listener to fetch real event from the stream/bus/wtf in given version. `$eventsStore->get($eventGuid, $eventType, 'v27')` for example (PHP syntax)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I gonna publish (internally) all my domain events and allow any other service to subscribe to them.

This is a common pattern in Even-Driven Architecture. I assume that you publish the events on an Event Broker, e.g. Apache Kafka and that Consumers subscribe to topics on the Event Broker.

> I am not longer allowed to change my events. This is even worse than local coupling because I don't event know my consumers any more. This limits the ability of developing/refactoring to unacceptable degree. I am thinking about versioning my events which solves most of the issues.

Nah, *published contracts* should be versioned and no backward incompatible changes can be added to them. If you need a change that is not backward compatible, you have to introduce a new version of the *published contract* - and keep the old one as long as there is consumers. This is no different from REST-based interfaces - you have to fulfill your contracts.

With REST you may do this by using both `/v1/orders` and `/v2/orders` at the same time. With an Event-Driven Architecture you use two *topics* e.g. `orders-v1` and `orders-v2` - and these two contain data following a *schema*, e.g. [Avro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Avro).

With an Event-Driven Architecture, where the services are decoupled (with a broker in between), you can actually phase out the old producer, if you add a smaller transformer, e.g. that consume `orders-v2` and transform the events to the old format and publishes them on `orders-v1` - so both `v1` and `v2` is still published.

[Building Event-Driven Microservices](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08C9V1FC9) is a good book about this.